# Can Cloudfront + ELB change the query string of my request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We're running a react web app on AWS. The web app is hosted by an S3 bucket, and the API sits on elastic beanstalk. We use Cloudfront to consolidate this behind a single domain.

[image]

So far so good. The site loads, it can talk to the API.

The issue is, all API requests that reach our elastic beanstalk instance still have /api in the query string. This is fine for our API since we can control that, but we are deploying an instance of [tileserver-gl](https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl), which does not allow us to configure the root url to serve from.

It doesn't seem like I can configure Cloudfront to modify the query string to chop of the first part. E.g. so that `mysite.com/api/v1/users` would map to `fj935hf02.elasticbeanstalk.com/v1/users`.

How have others circumvented this issue?

Comment: Can't you do that from the source?

Comment: How do you mean? If the source requests anything apart from /api, then the request will not hit the API server.

Comment: ohoo, my bad!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, CloudFront can do modifications like that through [Lamdba@edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html). Specifically you could look at the `Origin request` function which can modify what is passed to the origin.

AWS provides also [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-query-string-examples) of such functions. [One](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-query-string-examples) of the examples shows how you can work work with query strings.

```
'use strict';

const querystring = require('querystring');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    
    /* When a request contains a query string key-value pair but the origin server
     * expects the value in a header, you can use this Lambda function to
     * convert the key-value pair to a header. Here's what the function does:
     * 1. Parses the query string and gets the key-value pair.
     * 2. Adds a header to the request using the key-value pair that the function got in step 1.
     */

    /* Parse request querystring to get javascript object */
    const params = querystring.parse(request.querystring);

    /* Move auth param from querystring to headers */
    const headerName = 'Auth-Header';
    request.headers[headerName.toLowerCase()] = [{ key: headerName, value: params.auth }];
    delete params.auth;

    /* Update request querystring */
    request.querystring = querystring.stringify(params);

    callback(null, request);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have experience of using Lamda@Edge for this kind of thing? Are there pitfalls you’re aware of?

Comment: @Hannesh Lambda@Edge is not free and has many limitations as compared to regular lambda. But if you want to modify the headers or query strings, I don't know of any other way in CloudFront.